# How to drop a via on Altium without Numeric Keypad?

Tags: altium

I have a small keyboard without numeric keyboard. Unfortunately, the only way I found to drop a via is to use the * keystroke.

[image]

Is there an alternative?

Comment: During routing? Press 2.

Comment: Oh nice ! But it drops the wrong via size :(

Comment: Hit tilde to see the other commands, or just look up Interactive Routing on the docs.

Comment: Damed it... Tilde isn't usable on Swiss/German keyboard. I Should go for an US keyboard.

Comment: Look at the interactive routing tips here https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/interactive-routing-pcb

Comment: You can use the physical Swiss/German keyboard, just switch it to the US keyboard layout in Windows :) Or use the Swiss Programmers keyboard, if there's such an option.

Comment: You can set any key to any action.  Check the setup options for customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are drawing using ***interactive track**,* you can start drawing for example on top layer, then just before the area you want the *via* in, tap the “**tab**” button and from the properties menu in the right side, change the layer from **top layer to bottom layer**, it will show you a via to place immediately. Just click “**tab**” again to go back and draw.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the layer while routing with ctrl + shift + mouse wheel. This will allow you to place a via and continue routing on the new layer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use p+v (hold p then press v). it is a helpful shortcut then you can change the size with pressing tab. you can use template via which is a very simple and useful menu.